# How can i access children using parent id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this structure of html. To present the list of two different sets. and i must handle the click event differently.

```
<div id='nodelist1'>
<ul>
 <li class='nodeelem'>first node
    <ul>
      <li class='nodeelem'>second node
         <ul>
           <li class='nodeelem'>third node</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>


<div id='nodelist2'>
<ul>
 <li class='nodeelem'>first node
    <ul>
      <li class='nodeelem'>second node
         <ul>
           <li class='nodeelem'>third node</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have to access the nodes using div id

```
$('#nodelist1 li.nodeelem').click(handler);
$('#nodelist2 li.nodeelem').click(handler2);
```

Is this rightway to access children clicks???

Comment: Yes... This is the correct way.  Are you having problems with it?

Comment: Does this work for you?  If it does, then it's fine, otherwise...

Comment: Yes, if you want to access all the children at all the levels

Comment: Please don’t edit the question unless it’s a spelling mistake, it makes it difficult to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the hash `#` for ID selectors (although you corrected this in your edit):

```
$('#nodelist1 li.nodeelem').click(handler);
$('#nodelist2 li.nodeelem').click(handler2);
```

Tip: you can make the event more effective by using `on()` instead for event delegation:

```
$('#nodelist1').on('click', '.nodeelem', handler);
$('#nodelist2').on('click', '.nodeelem', handler2);
```